# How to get arn of AWS Api gateway when deploying with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to deploy a function and aws api gateway using cloudformation. In [LambdaPermission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-sourcearn) resource there is a property which is [SourceArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-sourcearn) and it expects the ARN of the resource that will invoke the function, in this case it will be api gateway. Now [ApiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html) resource does not provide the output value of arn. So my question is how we can access it?

here is the resource of Lambda Permission where I need to put the value in sourcearn.

```
LambdaPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
        Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        SourceArn: "How to get this value"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format:

```yaml
SourceArn:
  Fn::Join:
  - ''
  - - 'arn:'
    - !Ref AWS::Partition
    - ":execute-api:"
    - !Ref AWS::Region
    - ":"
    - !Ref AWS::AccountId
    - ":"
    - !Ref "Logical ID of resource of type AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    - "/"
    - !Ref "Logical ID of resource of type AWS::ApiGateway::Stage"
    - "/GET or POST or other HTTP Methods/your/resource/path/here"
```

An example:

```yaml
SourceArn:
  Fn::Join:
  - ''
  - - 'arn:'
    - !Ref AWS::Partition
    - ":execute-api:"
    - !Ref AWS::Region
    - ":"
    - !Ref AWS::AccountId
    - ":"
    - !Ref ApiGatewayRestApiResource
    - "/"
    - !Ref ApiGatewayStageResource
    - "/GET/example"
```

Comment: thanks @Kaustubh, This is 95% correct, you just have to use ! before ref. here is what I tried and it worked.

SourceArn: !Join [ ":", ["arn:aws:execute-api", !Ref AWS::Region, 
!Ref AWS::AccountId, !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi, "/*/POST/" ] ]

Comment: In YAML, both `Ref: logicalName` and `!Ref logicalName` should work. However i edited my answer to use `!Ref` since it worked correctly for you.

Comment: Can also use the `!Sub` function for more compact syntax

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an example of the more compact `!Sub` syntax [@henry-woody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8068625/henry-woody) suggested, here it is:

```
SourceArn: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApi}/*/GET/"
```